Given two nested (non concentric) circles, how can I calculate the distance between two points, one on each circle?
I've been trying to recreate this "Hugelshaffer Egg" animation in a 2d graphics programming environment. To get the egg I used the Cartesian parametrization listed on the site, which worked great. I was able to put the traveling circle around the egg using the same equation there, but I am missing how to create the other two traveling points and the right triangle between them.
My question is:
Given two nested (non concentric) circles, knowing the radius of both and how far offset from the center the inner circle is, how can I calculate the distance between two points, one on each circle?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Instead of requiring people to visit another site and read through a page of information to understand your question, please make your question as self-contained as possible by including all relevant details. ... Good luck!

Did you try the cosine rule?

@Intelligentipauca I have tried the cosine rule! It doesn't sem to account for the vertical offset (a known variable) between the center of the two circles. I believe these circles are known as "coaxial" but searching for that hasn't given me any luck either.
